# why write function isn't working?

Tags: c

im trying to read a file and write the content in other file, but the finish file is empty after program execution.

this is the code:

```
char buf[80];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int fd;
int fs;

if( (fd=open("salida.txt",O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR))<0) {
printf("\nError %d en open",errno);
perror("\nError en open");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if( (fs=open(argv[1],O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_RDONLY,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR))<0) {
printf("\nError %d en open",errno);
perror("\nError en open");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int cont = 1;
if(fs=read(fd,&buf,80) < 0){
cont++;
    if(write(fd,&buf,80) != 80) {
        perror("\nError en el write");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}
```

Comment: You tried to read from a `O_WRONLY` file descriptor.

Comment: You have problems with operator precedence.

Comment: regarding this line (and my comments also apply the other open statement:)  if( (fs=open(argv[1],O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_RDONLY,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR))<0) {  this line says that the file is to be readonly, BUT also says that is is read and write for the user (the user is the one executing your file

Comment: for flexability, this line: if(write(fd,&buf,80) != 80) { should be: if(write(fd,&buf,sizeof(buf)) != sizeof(buf)) {

Comment: this line: if(fs=read(fd,&buf,80) < 0){ overwrote the source file descriptor, and is trying to read from the destination file descriptor and buf is an array, '&buf' is actually taking the address of the address of the buf array. suggest: if( (int readStatus = (read( fs, buf, sizeof(buf) ) ) >0 ) { note: return value of <0 means an error occurred, so there is nothing to write.

Comment: Try doing a `man 2 open`, `man 2 read` and `man fread`. This will give you a good basic understanding of how to read and write files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition

```
if (fs=read(fd,&buf,80) < 0)
```

doesn't mean

```
if ((fs = read(fd,&buf,80)) < 0)
```

it means

```
if (fs = (read(fd,&buf,80) < 0))
```

and has the effect of overwriting the *file descriptor* `fs` with 0 if the read succeeds, and with 1 if it fails. (`read` returns the number of bytes read, or -1 on failure.)
You don't want to assign the result to `fs` in any case, as it means that you're destroying any possibility of writing to the file you opened.

Also, `fd` is apparently your output file, so it's slightly strange to read from it.

If you want to copy (up to) 80 bytes, you could say something like

```
int size = 0;
if((size = read(fs, buf, 80)) > 0){
    if (write(fd, buf, size) != size) {
        perror("\nError en el write");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Also, truncating the input file (`O_TRUNC`) may not be the best idea.

Comment: I made the change but the result it's the same

Comment: @rafaelleru Does the input file contain anything? (See edit.)

Comment: Yes it's the result of other program that works correctly @molbdnilo

Comment: @rafaelleru Check the contents of the input file *after* you have run the program you're asking about.

Comment: Nice catch on the operator precedence.  I never can remember them all so I often break these into 2 lines and let the compiler do the same thing... or I end up with ((((gobs) of) unnecessary) parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reading and writing from and to `fd`. Your code is not very clear, you may want to clean it up. As other answers have pointed out, there are multiple errors in your code and your intentions are not entirely clear.

You should comment your code and indent properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
   char ch;
   FILE *source, *target;

   source = fopen(source_file, "r");

   if( source == NULL )
   {
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   target = fopen(target_file, "w");

   if( target == NULL )
   {
      fclose(source);
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
      fputc(ch, target);

   printf("File copied successfully.\n");

   fclose(source);
   fclose(target);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It needs to be `int ch;`

Comment: You should declare `ch` as `int` to ensure getting `EOF` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You never closed the files. Most operating systems don't actually make changes to the files until you close them. Until then your changes are only visible in RAM and not on the hard drive. Just add:

```
close(fd);
close(fs);
```

To the end of your code.
There seem to be some other problems too (why are you reading from a write-only file and seemingly attempting to write the same data back to it), and it's very much unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
// the following compiles, but the @include statements do expect linux
// so if your using a different OS, you may have to update them.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (80)
static  char buf[ BUFFER_SIZE ]; // static so only visible in this file
// note: file scope variables are set to 0 by the startup code


int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd       = -1; // destination file descriptor
    int fs       = -1; // source file descriptor
    int statusRd =  0; // returned value from read
    int statusWr =  0; // returned value from write

    if( 2 > argc )
    { // then, file name parameter missing
        printf( "\ncalling format:  %s <filenametoread>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, proper number of parameters

    // note: there should be a call to 'stat()'
    //       to assure input file exists placed here

    // open destination file, uses fixed name
    if( (fd = open("salida.txt", O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IWRITE) ) <0)
    {
        printf("\nError %d en open",errno);
        perror("open for write failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, open of destination file successful

    if( (fs=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY,S_IREAD))<0)
    {
        printf("\nError %d en open",errno);
        perror("open for read failed");
        close(fd);  // cleanup
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, open of source file successful

    do
    {
        if( (statusRd = read(fs,&buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) < 0)
        { // then read failed
            perror( "read failed" );
            close(fs); // cleanup
            close(fd); // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, read successful

        if( 0 < statusRd )
        { // then some bytes read

            if( ( statusWr = write(fd, buf, statusRd)) < 0)
            { // then, write failed
                perror("\nwrite failed");
                close(fs); // cleanup
                close(fd); // cleanup
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    } while( statusRd > 0 ); // exit loop when reach end of file

    close(fs);
    close(fd);
    return(0);
}
```